# How customise Wordpress Docker image

Tags: wordpress, docker

My goal is to create a local environment for an old wordpress. Unfortunately, the
official Wordpress Docker images do not help me. The official images (https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) run on
debian and you can't change the PHP version in them. I would have to adapt the
image. I have already tried to change the PHP version within the running wordpress container. Unfortunately it did not work.

**Now my question**

Wordpress has to create a Dockerfile for the image, where the OS and PHP are
loaded. How do I get to the Dockerfile to learn from it and to adapt it to my
wishes?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the Dockerfile in their github repository:
https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/Dockerfile.template

in line 5, they get php with a Version defined in a Environment variable. If you change that to a Verison you need, it should install ths Version, but I don't know if that possibly destroys some other dependencies.